# Joomla module build. Dropdown list with database connection

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, module

I am trying to make a simple module for joomla 2.5. Essentially I want to be able to have a dropdown list with a persons riding. Once selected. The information for that district office/personal office would show up in a div below the dropdown box.

I eventually would like to have a second drop down list that would allow the user to choose office phone, personal phone, office email, personal email, office address or personal address, after first selecting the riding. That decided info would show up below the two drop down boxes. So far I have the module setup and installed (structure is correct). Just don't have the proper code in my helper.php and tmpl/default.php

HELPER.PHP

```
<?php
// No Access
defined('_JEXEC') or die ;

//Add database Instance
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
//Pass in query
$query = "SELECT * FROM #__mlainfo"; 
//Run it
$db -> setQuery($query);

//Load it as an object into variable "$ridings"
$riding = $db -> loadObjectList();
```

DEFAULT.PHP

```
<?php defined('_JEXEC') or die; ?>

<div class="moduletable<?php echo $params->get( 'moduleclass_sfx' ) ?>">
<select>
    <?php foreach ($riding as $riding_name => $ridings): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $riding_name ?>">
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
</div>
```

I realize I am only half way there. I get a select list to show up with this installed. However it just has 40 blank spaces. Any help would be appreciated.

All the info is stored in database with titles being;

riding(number), riding_name, full_name, off_address, per_address, off_email, per_email, off_phone, per_phone

Comment: I am new to Joomla and PHP, and looking for the same kind of thing you did. can you recommend or suggest any module or extension or plug in for this task..??
Any help will be very kind.

Comment: I ended up hiring a freelancer to build a module/extension for this as my coding was not quite up to the task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
loadObjectList() returns an indexed array of PHP objects

<div class="moduletable<?php echo $params->get( 'moduleclass_sfx' ) ?>">
<select>
    <?php foreach ($riding as $key => $ridings): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $ridings->riding?>"><?php echo $ridings->riding_name?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
</div>
```

http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase/1.5#loadObjectList.28.29

Hope this will help.

Comment: This worked. One further question what is the easiest way from this point to display the riding office info. Say the user selects this the third select option. I would like to display directly below the box the office info. Stored on same row in database.

Comment: @user1881482:One way is to use Ajax for onchange.And fetch data from db.Another way is to convert $riding data to json and call a function on "onchange" event and display data.

Comment: [link]http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp  Is this gonna work in a module?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to complete the option field:

```
<?php defined('_JEXEC') or die; ?>

<div class="moduletable<?php echo $params->get( 'moduleclass_sfx' ) ?>">
<select>
    <?php foreach ($riding as $riding_name => $ridings): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $ridings->riding ?>"><?php echo $ridings->riding_name ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: I had tried that before as well. It seems to just put in a value of ARRAY for all of the 40 previously blank items. How do I convert the array out to usable entities?

Comment: The `$ridings` variable will actually contain an object with all of the columns. You can use my updated code's syntax to get any value within the loop.

Comment: Thank you that all worked great. Any chance you could help tackle the second part? Populating a div with the office info from the associated choice in the drop down.